# Why my Hide/close drop down hamburger menu when click on #link didn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show-hide, hamburger-menu

I have hamburger menu on website. The problem is when I click on anchor link the menu doesn't close.
When it was regular link everything is okey becouse refreshing. But how to hide the menu after click on anchor link?

```
    var skipContents = $j('.skip-content');
    var skipLinks = $j('.skip-link');
    var searchField = $j('#search');

    skipLinks.on('click', function (e) {
        
        if ($j(this).hasClass('direct-link')) return true;
        e.preventDefault();

        var self = $j(this);
        var isNav = self.hasClass('skip-nav');
        var isCart = self.hasClass('skip-cart');
        var isSearch = self.hasClass('skip-search');
        var body = $j('body');
        // Use the data-target-element attribute, if it exists. Fall back to href.
        var target = self.attr('data-target-element') ? self.attr('data-target-element') : self.attr('href');

        // Get target element
        var elem = $j(target);

        // Check if stub is open
        var isSkipContentOpen = elem.hasClass('skip-active') ? 1 : 0;

        // Hide all stubs
        skipLinks.removeClass('skip-active');
        skipContents.removeClass('skip-active');

        // Toggle stubs
        if (isSkipContentOpen) {
            self.removeClass('skip-active');
            if (isNav) { body.removeClass('nav-open'); }
            if (isCart) { body.removeClass('cart-open'); }
        } else {
            self.addClass('skip-active');
            elem.addClass('skip-active');
            if (isNav) { body.addClass('nav-open'); }
            if (isCart) { body.addClass('cart-open'); }
            if (isSearch) { searchField.focus(); }
        }
    });

    $j('#header-cart').on('click', '.skip-link-close', function(e) {
        var body = $j('body');
        var parent = $j(this).parents('.skip-content');
        var link = parent.siblings('.skip-link');

        parent.removeClass('skip-active');
        link.removeClass('skip-active');
        body.removeClass('cart-open');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Can you please provide working snippet?

Comment: [link](https://samaeva.cz/) You can find it here.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
$j('a').on('click', function() {
  skipContents.filter('.skip-active').removeClass('skip-active');
  body.removeClass('nav-open');
});
```